# Javascript return value from multiple callback

Tags: javascript

I want to wait all callback functions finish and then return a final result, like this:

```
                    var jsonArray = new Array();

                    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        jQueryFunction(i, function(json){
                            jsonArray[i] = json;
                        });
                    }

                    return jsonArray;
```

jQueryFunction is a function which contains the asynchronous ajax and callback, return a value which is called json. I want to wait for the for loop finish and then put all the return values into jsonArray, return it finally.

My goal is that waiting for all jQueryFunction callbacks finish and store their return into jsonArray, and then return jsonArray at the end. My previous goal doesn't work because it returns the jsonArray right away and doesn't wait for the for loop

I tried like this:

```
                function jQueryFunction(ptd_url, callback)
                { 
                    $.ajax
                            ({
                                type: "GET",
                                async: true,
                                url: ptd_url,
                                dataType: "jsonp",
                                jsonp: "callback",
                                jsonpCallback: "tpsHandler",
                                success: function(json)
                                {
                                    return callback(json);
                                }
                            });  
                }

                function finalResultFunction()
                {
                    var jsonArray = new Array();

                    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        jQueryFunction(1, function(json){
                            jsonArray[i] = json;
                            alert(jsonArray[i]);
                        });
                    }

                    $.when.apply($, jsonArray).done(function(){
                      alert(jsonArray[0]);
                    ...
                 }

                 setInterval(finalResultFunction,1000);
```

The first alert shows me the correct object, but the second one still shows me null. Why? How to fix it?

Comment: so what's your _specific_ question?

Comment: *I want to wait for the for loop finish*. Are you using synchronous AJAX, then?

Comment: What's `jQueryFunction` ?

Comment: If jQueryFunction is asynchronous, not going to happen.

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581951/waiting-for-event-to-be-handled-to-continue-executing-the-function-that-has-trig/18799935#18831177

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery's `when` to wait on multiple requests.  You just need the `jQueryFunction` to return the `jqXHR`.

```
function jQueryFunction(){
    return $.ajax( /* ... */ );
}

var requests = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var xhr = jQueryFunction( /* ... */ );

    requests.push(xhr);
}

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function(){

    // EVERYTHING IS NOW DONE, DO SOMETHING HERE

});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If I use jQueryFunction(i,function(json){ jsonArray.push(json);  });

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than just "doesn't work".  What does it to and are there errors on the console.  The concept works.

Comment: Your posted code is nothing like the code I have in my answer.  You didn't make your `jQueryFunction` return the xhr (the result of the ajax function) and you are calling `when` on an empty array instead of an array of these `xhr` objects

Comment: I use callback to return the value. And because ajax is the asynchronous function, I don't know how to return a value like you provide above

Comment: That's the whole problem.  You can't use your callback to return a value.  That will never work.  This might be a good read.  It's kind of long but the content is really helpful in understanding all of the issues around ajax  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38644/discussion-between-user2597504-and-james-montagne)